# What is this paradoxical entity?

Tags: riddle

I have always been there,
and will always be.
I'll be gone in a mere
moment, you'll see.

You cannot remember
me to not be with you,
yet just at the moment,
I'm completely new.

You cannot escape me,
nor stay within me.
Now could you please tell me,
do you recognize me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off CodeNewbie's answer, I think the answer might be

> The present

I have always been there,
and will always be.

> The present has always existed, and will continue to exist.

I'll be gone in a mere
moment, you'll see.

> Your current point in time is the present, but in a moment that point in time will be the past.

You cannot remember
me to not be with you,

> I don't actually understand this part, I'm having trouble parsing it, but probably something to do with anything you "remember" is in the past, not the present.

yet just at the moment,
I'm completely new.

> The present moment is always a new moment.

You cannot escape me,
nor stay within me.

> You will always be in the present, but you can never stay in the present moment.

Now could you please tell me,
do you recognize me?

> The present!

Comment: Exactly, that's the answer. About the line you didn't understand: Whatever moment you remember, it was the [redacted] at that time.

Answer (score 1):

You are

> breath

I have always been there, and will always be.

> A living person will always be breathing.

I'll be gone in a mere moment, you'll see.

> A single breath vanishes in a moment.

You cannot remember me to not be with you,

> A person can't remember when they weren't breathing.

yet just at the moment, I'm completely new.

> A person is always taking new breaths.

You cannot escape me,

> You can't stop breathing.

nor stay within me.

> It's not possible for a person to be inside a breath.

Comment: Good idea, but that's not the searched term. Also, you can stop breathing (hold your breath), just not for long.

Answer (score 1):

A very cliched answer, but I think it is

> Time

I have always been there,
and will always be.

> Time has existed before us and will continue to exist after us.

I'll be gone in a mere
moment, you'll see.

> Time passes us by every second.

You cannot remember
me to not be with you,

> You recall past instances by associating them with a point in time.

yet just at the moment,
I'm completely new.

> Every moment in time is unique.

You cannot escape me,
nor stay within me.

> You cannot escape the clutches of time, and you constantly struggle to finish off your tasks within a certain time frame.

Now could you please tell me,
do you recognize me?

> I do recognize you. You're my old foe, Time!

Comment: Very close, but not the searched term.